# mysql select statement giving wrong output

Tags: mysql

mysql database select statement giving wrong output
this is the image of the table 
[image]

what i want is not show a data if one of its status is declined so basically number 2 will not appear . so far the query is working.

```
select number 
from document 
group by number 
having sum(`status` = 'declined') = 0
```

but if i add where statement. the output is wrong. and the query look like this

```
select number 
from document 
where tr = "0002" 
group by number 
having sum(`status` = 'declined') = 0
```

Comment: i forgot to add the output. the output is number 1 2 3

Comment: What is your desired output? Groups that have at least one entry with tr=2 and no entry that is declined?